# Where to get the EPUB syntax specifications?

Tags: syntax, specifications, epub

I need to know the details about how an EPUB is written, where i can get the official specs? Which is the entity that cares about the EPUB format?

Comment: Did you read the tag wikis you used on the question and how could improve the entries?

Comment: @Mark the search does not shows anything useful to me

Comment: What search? The tag buttons give a link to more info which includes the IDPF

Comment: @Mark can you give me a link? you mean the questions selected by tag?

Comment: @user827992 Here [it](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/epub/info) is.

Comment: When you chose the epub tag it gave a pop up that included a link to the tag wiki - now click on the epub button - the more info should give enough information if not what more should it give.

Comment: @Mark Dear Mark, it's the "info" link, that's the reason why i see no "wiki" link. Anyway i need the specs, and i stil can't find them written in a pdf doc or something, i will try the provided links in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifications are [here](http://idpf.org/epub/30).

The organisation that controls it is  International Digital Publishing Forum (IDPF) as noted in the [epub](/questions/tagged/epub) tag wiki

Answer (score 2):

The [International Digital Publishing Forum](http://idpf.org/) defines [specifications](http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-overview.html) for EPUB.